# Struct memory allocation, memory allocation should be in multiple of 4

Tags: c, memory, struct

```
struct x
{
  char b;
  short s;
  char bb;
};


int main()
{
 printf("%d",sizeof(struct x));
}
```

Output is : 6

I run this code on a 32-bit compiler. the output should be 8 bytes.

**My explanation** --> 1. Char needs 1 bytes and the next short takes multiple of 2 so short create a padding of 1 and take 2 bytes, here 4 bytes already allocated. Now the only left char member takes 1 byte but as the memory allocates is in multiple of 4 so overall memory gives is 8 bytes.

Comment: Too many assumptions.

Comment: "the memory allocates is in multiple of 4" what?? and use `stdint` types instead of `short`.

Comment: [Typical alignment of C structs on x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86)

Comment: What text suggested "the memory allocates is in multiple of 4"?

Comment: Did you observe that `sizeof(struct{short s;})` is 4?

Comment: @jxh This make sense, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alignment requirement of a struct is that of the member with the maximum alignment. The max alignment here is for `short`, so probably `2`. Hence, two for `b`, two for `s`, and two for `bb` gives 6.

Comment: This is the most plausible answer. Realize, though, that these results could vary based on many things.

Answer (score 0):

The C struct memory layout is completely implementation-specific and you can't assume all of this.

Also, in the typical alignment of C structs a struct like this:

```
struct MyData
{
    short Data1;
    short Data2;
    short Data3;
};
```

will also have sizeof = 6 because if the type "short" is stored in two bytes of memory then each member of the data structure depicted above would be 2-byte aligned. Data1 would be at offset 0, Data2 at offset 2, and Data3 at offset 4. The size of this structure would be 6 bytes.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: "then each member of the data structure depicted above would be 2-byte aligned" --> That certainly is what is happening in OP's case, yet C does not require that.  Member `ss` could be 1,2,4 or other exotic bytes away from `b`.  "layout is completely implementation-specific" is very true.